# Extracting values from keys inside multiple key-value pair arrays with dart/flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, object

Below I have a simple array that contains key-value pairs.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

If 'global' == true, print the value of the 'title' key inside that same object. If 'global' == false, do nothing.

So for the example below, we would only print 'hello'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
void main() {

var messages = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'title': "hello",
    'global': true,
  }, 
  {
    'id': 2,
    'title': "bye",
    'global': false,
  }, 
];
```

Comment: `print(messages.where((m) => m['global'] == true).map((m) => m['title']));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply iterate into `messages`:

```
  var messages = [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'title': "hello",
      'global': true,
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'title': "bye",
      'global': false,
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'title': "hi",
      'global': true,
    },
  ];

  messages.forEach((element) {
    element["global"] == true ? print(element["title"]) : null;
  });
```

**Output:**

```
hello
hi
```